# Link to a Game in the Marketplace from XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

How do you link to an app in the Windows Phone marketplace from within an XNA game?

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted twice. It seems like a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: Thanks. I also couldn't find this question anywhere. Maybe people don't like short questions? :/

Comment: Not sure, either, other than the answer wasn't hard to find using your Bing Fu.

Comment: Well, I had been searching for over an hour. All promising links pointed to the app hub forums, for which all links are broken with the new site...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MarketplaceDetailTask

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394017(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: Ok, that just worked (though I forgot to add a reference to Microsoft.Phone.Tasks first). Thank you.

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore so use this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394017(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rich's answer, it's also worth pointing out that there is also `Guide.ShowMarketplace`, which seems to be preferred for XNA (because it is an XNA API). But it isn't as flexible as `MarketplaceDetailTask`.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew.  I have seen this one, but since I haven't yet done anything in XNA, I don't know what the limitations are.

Comment: What I am getting from the documentation is that `ShowMarketplace` will go to the currently running game's page so you may purchase it. Whereas `MarketplaceDetailTask` can go to any page.

Comment: Thanks - I'd wondered if that's what it was.  The way I took the question was if he was trying to link to a different app, which isn't a bad marketing idea.

Comment: That was exactly the idea Rich, I'm doing cross promotion between my games. Guide.ShowMarketplace was indeed not what I needed, but thank you, too, Andrew.